# Invert the numbers

Tags: number-theory

I have an array of numbers containing 0 and 1 only and you are given a a constant C . You have to invert all the 0's to 1's by taking exactly C number of elements . What is the max number of 1's we can get ? You can do inversion operation any number of times . **C <= N** always

For eg1 : [ 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1] **N** = 5 and **C** = 3 ans is 5

For eg2 : [ 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ,1 ] **N** = 7 and **C** = 3 ans is 7

Explanation for eg 1 : -

[ 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 ] - > [ 0 ,1 , 0 ,0 , 1 ] -> [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1, 1 ]

Comment: Where did you find this puzzle?

Comment: It was asked by my friend . He says it is similar to die hard water jug problem

Comment: I tried this question and find out that it depends on count of one's and count of zero's  and k . If we can have even number of zero's on 1 side and any number of one another side such that we can always take value equal to k . Then we can make all 0's to 1

Comment: I don't understand the explanation, I thought (1) we invert C at a time and (2) we end up with 4 ones (you've ended up with 5)

Comment: srry by mistake wrote C=2

Comment: You've still somehow ended with five ones :/

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to get to four ones in a single step anyway? (`00011 -> 11101`)

Comment: Also is it *any* C elements or do they need to form a contiguous slice?

Comment: srry again taken a wrong example i guess :'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94979/discussion-between-aki-and-jonathan-allan).

Comment: It doesn't matter that number of 1 are continuous or not

Comment: You've already asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264457/invert-the-numbers) also I think this question was already asked by a user and I think it was a from a contest

Comment: Yep . Someone Suggested me that this question is a good place for puzzling that's y  i also post here . Before that i didn't even know about puzzling . This question was asked by my friend and i was solving this which is an intermediate phase of it . I also asked the even odd problem on math exchange because i thought it can help me to solved this problem

Comment: There is a policy against cross-posting and, more seriously, against posting questions that are part of an active competition. Can you get a more accurate source for this puzzle to ensure that it does not violate these policies, please?

Comment: This appears to be a weaker version of [A series of blocks (total $n + m$) is given to us and 0 is stored initially in each.We are given a number $H$ and we can choose $H$ blocks at a time](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/85029), likely having lost something in the process of trying to obfuscate it from whatever form this question originally appeared.